# Technique of Counting problem

Tags: probability

If we have an urn containing 6 red, 4 white and 8 black balls. You should draw a sample of 5 balls what is the probability of obtaining 3 red balls if the problem was with replacement when you draw a red ball you but another red one and also the same for white and black balls ?

I got to the following answer (6/18)^3 multiplied by (12/18)^2 .. but I believe it's probability for one child of the tree so I must multiply this by the number of combinations of 5 balls containing 3 red ones ... I can't get to the number of combinations !

Comment: At least $3$ red balls or exactly $3$ red balls?

Comment: Exactly 3 red balls

Comment: Sorry, Barak I forgot to declare that drawing is with replacement .. when you draw a red ball you but another red one and also the same for white and black can you help please ?

Comment: Added to the original answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Drawing with replacement:

---

The total number of combinations is:

$$(6+4+8)^5=1889568$$

---

The number of combinations with $3$ red balls is:

$$\binom{5}{3}\cdot(6)^3\cdot(4+8)^{5-3}=311040$$

---

So the probability of obtaining exactly $3$ red balls is:

$$\frac{311040}{1889568}\approx16.46\%$$

---

### Drawing without replacement:

---

The total number of combinations is:

$$\binom{6+4+8}{5}=8568$$

---

The number of combinations with $3R+1W+1B$ is:

$$\binom{6}{3}\cdot\binom{4}{1}\cdot\binom{8}{1}=640$$

---

The number of combinations with $3R+2W+0B$ is:

$$\binom{6}{3}\cdot\binom{4}{2}\cdot\binom{8}{0}=120$$

---

The number of combinations with $3R+0W+2B$ is:

$$\binom{6}{3}\cdot\binom{4}{0}\cdot\binom{8}{2}=560$$

---

So the probability of obtaining exactly $3$ red balls is:

$$\frac{640+120+560}{8568}\approx15.41\%$$

Comment: Thanks again ! That's helpful :)

Comment: @AhmedEl-Gamal: You're welcome :)

Comment: Single point I can't understand is that why number of combinations is 5C3

Comment: @AhmedEl-Gamal: Choose $3$ out of $5$ places for the red balls. For example: the first ball that you pick, the second ball that you pick and the last ball that you pick. The remaining $2$ places will be left for the non-red balls.

Comment: Were not different places for red balls considered when I multiply 6^3 * 12^2 so why I am to arrange the balls again ?

Comment: @AhmedEl-Gamal: No, with this you are taking into account only the colors, not the places. And for fairness, you should accept the same answer you've accepted before you added the notion that `drawing is with replacement`.

Comment: @AhmedEl-Gamal: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to discern $6$ red balls and $12$ balls that are not red.

So the probability to draw exactly $3$ red balls is: $$\frac{\binom63\binom{12}2}{\binom{18}{5}}$$

Same idea and outcome as in Baraks answer but the calculation is a bit less complicated.

---

If there is replacement of the drawn balls then you are dealing with binomial distribution having parameters $n=5$ and $p=\frac6{18}=\frac13$ wich is the probability to draw a red ball in this context. Then $$P(R=3)=\binom53\left(\frac13\right)^3\left(\frac23\right)^2$$
where $R$ denotes the number of red balls that are drawn exactly.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to declare that drawing is with replacement .. when you draw a red ball you but another red one and also the same for white and black can you help please

Comment: Single point I can't understand is that why number of combinations is 5C3

Comment: If you must choose $3$ out of $5$ then there are $5C3$ possibilities. Do you understand that? It is very elementary. Here there are $5$ balls and $3$ of them are red. That gives possibilities like RRNRN, RNNRR, et cetera. The sequence RRNRN stands for: the first ball drawn is red, the second is red, the third is not red, the fourth is red and the fifth is not red.

Comment: I just think when I multiply 6C3 x 12C2 it was enough for both colors and places

Comment: In your last comment you return to drawings **without** replacement. Also you did not answer the question in my former comment (Do you understand that?).

Comment: I understand combination rule in general, but I can not apply it on this very problem

Comment: $5$ balls are drawn and exactly $3$ of them are red. That gives $5C3=10$ possibilities when it comes to the order (RRRNN, RRNRN, et cetera). Each possibility has a probability of $\frac4{243}$ to occur. So the summation of these probabilities is $10\times\frac4{243}$.